# Ruby binary string to hexadecimal without loosing 0000

Tags: ruby

I have a binary string that I need to convert to a hexadecimal string. I have this code that does it pretty well

```
binary = '0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
binary.to_i(2).to_s(16)
```

This will normally work but in this situation, the first four zeros, representing the first hexadecimal place is left out. So instead of 
`0400000000000000` it is showing `400000000000000`.

Now, I know i can loop through the binary string manually and convert 4 bits at a time, but is there a simpler way of getting to my wanted result of '0400000000000000'?

Would rjust(16,'0') be my ideal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
binary = "0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
[binary].pack("B*").unpack("H*").first
# => "0400000000000000"
```

`binary.to_i(2)` will convert the value to a number. A number does not know about leading zeros. `pack("B*")` will convert 8 bit each to a byte, giving you a binary encoded String. 8 x 0 is `"\x00"`, a zero byte. So unlike the number, the string preserves the leading zeros. `unpack("H*")` then converts 4 bits each into their hex representation. See `Array#pack` and `String#unpack` for more information.

Comment: Note this does have problems - delete the zero on the right for instance, and it will not change the value, despite the hex representation now properly being "0200000000000000"

Comment: Whether that is a problem depends on uptownhr's use case. Due to the way it was asked, I assume that any input which is not a multiple of 8 bits is not valid.

Comment: True, worth explaining the match to use case in the answer. I would generally expect the binary leading zeroes to represent something of fixed length. Although for conversion to hex, only multiples of 4 bits are necessary, it would be unusual to want this code to handle e.g. 28 binary digits to 7 hex digits.

Comment: There is also `unpack1` that returns the first extracted value, so you can omit the `first` call: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-unpack1

Answer (score 2):

You should use string format for such complicated results.

```
"%016x" % binary.to_i(2)
# => "0400000000000000"
```

Comment: That requires you to either know the resulting length or calculate it.

Comment: Can someone explain further on how this works? I'm not understanding how this makes 16 and the syntax is off to me.

Comment: @apeiros The question was not clear on that point. I interpreted that the length is fixed since the OP is considering `rjust(16,'0')`. I took the `16` from there.

Comment: @uptownhr [Here are the Docs for `String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) it formats an argument based on a string format pattern as defined in [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf). In this case the format is "016" pad with 16 0 (zeros) "x" Convert Argument as a hexadecimal number. All `sprintf` formats are preceded by "%"